# CMD/PowerShell start app with passed "Start in" path parameter without creating shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Sorry if this has been answered anywhere already, but can't find any legitimate topic about it.

I'm having what seems to be simple problem, but am yet to find elegant solution.

I'm trying to run an exe from command line (or PowerShell) in such way that I can pass the "Start in" path parameter to it. Reason for doing so is, that I have updated exe files on network drive, that rely on local DLLs to which it has relative path, so it needs them in same folder.

I do not want to simply copy-paste the file in the original folder and overwrite the original one. At the moment, one of the options to do that is creating the .lnk shortcut file next to the exe, with "Start in" parameter being set to the local folder containing .dll files.
I want to avoid the need of creating .lnk file and want to know if is it possible to directly call the .exe file with passed parameter just like the .lnk passes them?

I've tried to do it with a command `processname.exe /K "cd /D C:\originalPathWithDlls"`  but that doesn't seem to work for other than command line window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `cmd` command line any of these will work

```
start "" /d "x:\where\dlls\are" "w:\the\file.exe"
wmic process call create "w:\the\file.exe", "x:\where\dlls\are"
```

From powershell, you can use

```
start-process -FilePath "w:\the\file.exe" -WorkingDirectory "x:\where\dlls\are"
([wmiclass]"win32_Process").create("w:\the\file.exe", "x:\where\dlls\are")
```

Comment: Oh my! It's just as easy as that! :O Thanks!

Comment: On a side note though - this works in cmd but doesn't go through in powershell. Using Invoke-Expression is a way around it, but do you perhaps know how to do the same directly in PS as well? Thanks!